# Should I leave my job now or after promotion even though I already tried to resign?

Tags: career-development, resignation, promotion

I want to leave my current job as the pay is not good enough and it was my first full time job which I initially took on to gain some experience.

I am planning on going on leave for 1 month from mid July to mid August this year due to personal family reasons. This came up quite suddenly so my annual leave only covers 2 weeks.

I thought this is the best time to leave so I handed in my resignation explaining my personal circumstances but also saying that I was looking for other jobs.

My manager offered to extend my leave so it covers the whole month and assured me my career will progress i.e. I will likely get promoted soon.

I definitely don't want to stay in this job forever, so should I leave before my 1 month leave or after my 1 month leave when I get promoted?
Also I don't have another job lined up which makes me lean towards staying, getting the promotion, and then start looking for other jobs whilst being employed. Also, if I leave before my 1 month leave, it is a bit difficult searching for jobs due to the limited time frame as ideally I would want to have a new job lined up after I come back from my leave.

On the other hand, the pay is quite awful even when I get promoted and I don't know if I will end up on bad terms with the company if I leave 2-3 months after my promotion as they are now already aware that I want to leave.

I am very confused...any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should get that other job before you make any decisions.

Comment: Your main issue seems that you don't want to leave on bad terms but I don't think you will. If you almost resigned they would understand that this new job doesn't fit you either and you needed to try it to understand it's more than money (or any political lie you can think of).

Comment: I'm with Yoda: "Do or do not. There is no try."  Resign, or don't resign.  There is no trying to resign.

Comment: Take the promotion and keep working until you find a job.

Comment: take your leaves. Take promotion. Keep searching. Resign once you get a job. LIke others said, dont resign with out other job in hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're motivated to find a new job and it doesn't sound like the promotion changes that at all: the money still isn't good enough and you want to move forward with your career.

If you only get promotions when threatening to leave, you'll likely have to threaten to leave for the next promotion, and the next. It doesn't sound like a positive or rewarding way to progress your career to me.

The traditional wisdom is to resign only after accepting an offer from another company and I don't see any reason not to follow that here. Keep looking for a new job and hand your notice in once you've got something lined up. You've still got plenty of time before you go away to sort this out but depending on your industry, experience and location it might take a while.

If your current company promote you while they know you are looking for other jobs, they really shouldn't be surprised if you resign after holding the new position for a 2-3 months. If they are annoyed about it then they'll likely find some reason to be annoyed whenever you leave.

Keep working as if you aren't going to leave, take the promotion, and resign when you've got a new job agreed. Anything else risks you being left without any work for an indefinite amount of time.